# How to handle type-dynamic force:navigateToObjectHome in Lightning Out?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, urlfor, lightning-events

To make a Lightning component also navigate properly in Classic I am capturing events in a **Lightning-Out** Visualforce page and transform them for the Classic world.

I didn't came up with a way to handle `force:navigateToObjectHome` so. I can't use `URLFOR(Action.Tab)` as I only know the object type in the client.

```
    $Lightning.use("c:mycomp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(component, attributes, divId, function(cmp) {
                $A.eventService.addHandler({ event: "force:closeQuickAction", handler: function(event) {
                    window.history.back();
                }});

                $A.eventService.addHandler({ event: "force:navigateToSObject", handler: function(event) {
                    var recordId = event.getParam("recordId");
                    window.location = "/" + recordId;
                }});


                $A.eventService.addHandler({ event: "force:navigateToObjectHome", handler: function(event) {
                    var sobjectType = event.getParam("sObjectName");
                    // HOW TO MAKE THIS WORK ???
                    window.location = "{!URLFOR($Action[" + sobjectType + "].Tab)}";
                }});
            }); // createComponent
        }); // use
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, if you know what object types you're dealing with, would be to hardcode a map.

```
var nameToPrefixLookUp = { 'Account' : '001', 'Contact' : '003'..}
//then in your code
window.location = '/' + nameToPrefixLookUp[sobjectType];
```

This is going to fall short if you won't know the full list of objects, or if you're using custom objects and sandboxes.

The next easiest way would be to create a small apex method capable of return the prefix from name.

```
@auraenabled
public static String getPrefix(String oName){
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult[] descResult = Schema.describeSObjects(new String[]{oName});
    return descResult[0].getKeyPrefix();//more error handling would be ideal
}
```

Then call this and redirect in the callback.